# Writing customized xpath for locating web table elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I was recently a part of an interview at General Electric Company for the role of QA Engineer/SDET.
I was asked this question by the interviewer:

Navigate to "*[https://selectorshub.com/xpath-practice-page/*"](https://selectorshub.com/xpath-practice-page/*%22) and scroll down to **SYSTEM DISTRIBUTION DETAILS**(Web Table) and write a customized xpath to capture all the rows that has **windows as OS**, **chrome as browser**, **Samsun as city** and **India as country**.

I was unable to answer the question completely and I am still stuck with it.

If someone has a solution for this kindly help.

[image: WebTable Image]

I tried to capture all the row elements having India as country in a List and iterated through the List using Iterator object.

Comment: Thanks to share your code.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And the point is that you need to understand what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath for you case would be

```xml
//*[@id='tablepress-1']//tr[.//*[text()='windows' and @class='column-2'] and .//*[text()='chrome' and @class='column-3'] and .//*[text()='Samsun' and @class='column-4'] and .//*[text()='India' and @class='column-5']]
```

Where you're:

1. Getting element with id `tablepress-1` (table)
2. Getting all `tr` which has childs with `class` that corresponding columns with unique data and it's text (`tr[.//*[@class='class' and text()='text']`) syntax
3. For OS class is `column-2` and text is 'windows'
4. For Browser class is `column-3` and text is 'chrome'
5. For City class is `column-4` and text is 'samsun'
6. For Country class is `column-5` and text is 'India'

I should note, that constructing such locator is bad practice, as far as it's heavy operation for driver and this locator is hard to read.

It's better to get rows elements and filter corresponding cell by containing correct data via programming language functions. It would be faster and easier to support and understand.